# YouTube embed start at specific time not working

Tags: youtube, embed

I have the following YouTube embed code, to start a video at a specific time. It used to work a few weeks ago, but it's not working now:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/A2_yg19Pu7Y?start=150&version=3&rel=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=A2_yg19Pu7Y" allow="autoplay;accelerometer;clipboard-write;encrypted-media;gyroscope;picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="1092.8" height="614.7" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The video is supposed to start at 2m 30s, but it starts from the beginning.

Did something change on YouTube side in the past few weeks?

**EDIT:** It appears, when the embed link contains the **playlist** parameter (needed for looping the video - https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), the video does not start from the specified time, it starts from the beginning instead. I need to keep the playlist parameter, but also start the video at the given start time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I don't think anything changed on YouTube's side.

I went to your link:

```
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/A2_yg19Pu7Y?start=150&version=3&rel=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=A2_yg19Pu7Y" allow="autoplay;accelerometer;clipboard-write;encrypted-media;gyroscope;picture-in-picture
```

And it started at 2:30, like you wanted. That being said, you have a blank space between `...playlist=A2_yg19Pu7Y"` and  `allow="autoplay...`, and it looks like your double quotes may be escaping the string. Try deleting that blank space and your video will hopefully work!

Edit: I just did a little research and found that "allow" is an HTML attribute, so the link should probably work as it is at the moment. That being said, if you haven't tested it already, then you should try the whole link as one string for the `src=` attribute to make sure its working.

Comment: I tried the embed URL with each parameter (start, rel, version, ...) and identified that when there is "playlist" parameter, the video starts from the beginning, when I remove "playlist" parameter, video starts at the specified start time. I'm now seeking a way to keep playlist parameter but also start from the specified time.

Comment: The "playlist" parameter is needed to loop the video. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're trying to loop the video, and make it start at 2:30 whenever it loops?

Comment: It would be enough if it started at 2:30 at the first play. Then loop from the beginning after the 1st play. Perhaps, it's not possible with the iframe embed code...

Comment: Check this StackOverflow question out: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45884/have-an-embedded-youtube-video-loop-end-at-specified-time-every-time-it-plays There seems to be a JavaScript YouTube API you can leverage, and the top answer seems to be using the iFrame API with the YouTube embed. Hopefully you can get something out of that!